# Where should .htaccess be located for a www.example.com/abc/

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I've got a set of webpages-A at www.example.com and I want to setup a set of scripts-B at the location: www.example.com/abc/

I've got an existing .htaccess which is "configured" to be located at an address like www.example.com/ (not within the subfolder)

Where should the .htaccess be located? At www.example.com/ or at www.example.com/abc/

Its currently at the latter, but its not redirecting properly.

**How do I check if the url rewriting module is installed properly?**

---

Edit 1: Solution

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, changed:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

To

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your .htaccess file in the server folder abc - so you need to check the path to the root of your site, and then put the .htaccess in the abc folder in that root folder.

For example, `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/example_site_root/abc` <- put .htaccess here.

Comment: darn - its actually there... so I guess the rewrite module isnt installed / working - how can I definitely check that?

Comment: You need to check whether your host directive allows .htaccess to override the httpd.conf settings - there should be a line with 'AllowOverride`.  Check that your httpd.conf file has lines saying `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and `AddModule mod_rewrite.c` and they aren't commented out.  See also  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Ahh... I did the first. The second line was already present and I didnt need to do the third... (see edit 1)